# Separating similiar object in an image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-segmentation

I have posted a question on Stackoverflow and was suggested to post here.

Please refer this question for the images: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534202/seperating-similiar-object-in-an-image-opencv-python):

I have used SURF Keypoints and a **FLANN Based matcher** and plotted the matching Keypoints as circles and then drawn the rectangle grouping all the keypoints.
As you can see, there are multiple vehicles matching the Template. I want to group the keypoints in a way such that I can get the count of the matching Vehicles.
How can I go about doing this?
I know that I can't just use a clustering method because, I need to group them more than just spatially.